# How to read www-site properly?

Tags: python, python-3.3

I tried to read WWW-site on my Python project. However, the code will crash if I can't connect to the Internet. How can catch the exception if there is no connection during some point of reading the site?

```
import sys
import time
import urllib3

# Gets the weather from foreca.fi.
def get_weather(url):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', url)
    return (r.data)

time = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
url = "http://www.foreca.fi/Finland/Kuopio/Saaristokaupunki/details/" + time 
weather_all = get_weather(url)
print(weather_all)
```

Comment: ummm use a try/except clause?

Comment: I am quite sure that it does not "crash" - it may raise an Exception. And this will be the answer: You need a try-except-block to catch the exception. Next time please add the "Crash" Message (Exception Stack Trace)

Comment: As an aside, did you plan to actually use the `time` value?

Comment: @tripleee Yes. I forgot that. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code with no connection, if there's no connection it will raise and [MaxRetryError](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/blob/master/urllib3/exceptions.py) ("Raised when the maximum number of retries is exceeded.") so you can handle the exception something like:

```
try:
    # Your code here
except urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError:
    # handle the exception here
```

Another thing you can do is to use a timeout and do something special when it times out, so that you have additional control.  which in a sense what the exception raised it telling you, that it hit the max amount

Also, consider working with [requests library](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

I presume urllib3 would `throw` a `URLError` exception if there is no route to the specified server (i.e. the internet connection is lost), so perhaps you could use a simply `try catch`? I'm not particularly well versed in urllib3, but for urllib it would be something like:

E.g.

```
try:
  weather_all = get_weather(url)
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
  print "No connection to host"
```

Comment: Hmm. I got urllib3.exception.MaxRetryError: and during handling of the above exception, I got NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined.

Comment: urllib is a different library, you have to use urllib3, check my answer.

Comment: It seems like urllib3 handles this sort of thing by retrying over and over until the MaxRetryError occurs. I'd say go with lv10's answer.